# AngularJS, Google SEO and page titles

Tags: angularjs, seo

I am having an issue with google webmaster tools and my angular application.
For some reason page titles are not being displayed.
I am using ui-router so I had set this up:

```
<title ng-bind="'Page title | ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
```

in my index page an then my app had this:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AccountService', 'SettingsService', function ($rootScope, $state, account, settings) {

    // Apply the state to the rootscope
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
}
```

And when defining states, I had the data set like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/home.tpl.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Home'
    }
})
```

But this was not geting picked up via webmaster tools. So I had a bit of a google around and someone had had the same issue, they solved it by creating a service.
So I created a service like this:

```
.service('PageTitle', function() {
    var title = 'Kudos Sports';
    return {
        title: function() { 
            return title; 
        },

        setTitle: function(newTitle) { 
            title = newTitle; 
        }
    };
})
```

Then on my index page, I did this:

```
<!-- Required to make our application crawlable -->
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title ng-bind="controller.title()"></title>

<!-- Removed for brevity -->
```

my HeadController, just looks like this:

.controller('HeadController', ['PageTitle', function (service) {
    var self = this;

```
self.title = service.title;
```

}]);;

and then in my state declarations, I did this:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/home.tpl.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    resolve: {
        pageTitle: ['PageTitle', function (service) {
            service.setTitle('Kudos Sports - Home');
        }]
    }
})
```

After a couple of weeks, I have checked back and my page titles are still not being seen.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: https://prerender.io/

Comment: You must follow google guidelines for SEO in ajax driven pages. Don't expect them to read the same front end that users see properly

Comment: I followed all the guidelines, it should be working but isn't. @sp00m prerender.io was used prior to google crawling javascript, so it shouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: @r3plica so did you find answer to this question?

Comment: yeah, it was google. Their web master tools are slightly behind the curve. I have tested on many other sites and the titles are displayed and google itself picks up the page titles.

Answer (score 0):

AngualrJS is outdated so I will not recommend using it, still, if you have used it you, update to higher angular version or REact or Veu. Still here is the fix for SEO, updating meta tags.

```
  <update-link rel="canonical" href="{{url}}"></update-link>
  <update-meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}"></update-meta>
  <update-meta name="description" content="{{description}}"></update-meta>
  <update-meta name="twitter:title" content="{{title}}"></update-meta>
  <update-meta name="twitter:description" content="{{description}}"></update-meta>
  <update-meta name="twitter:image" content="{{image}}"></update-meta>
```